# Using smart pointers with Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm not quite quite sure how to use smart pointers.
I have to create Smart class which will handle those smart pointers , and it should include  `operator*()` and `operator->()` functions.

I've created LinkedList class:

```
class LinkedList
{
private:
    typedef struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
    }* nodePtr;

    nodePtr emptyPtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;
public:
    LinkedList();
    void AddNode(int addData);
    void DeleteNode(int delData);
    void PrintList();
    ~LinkedList();
};
```

and I have a Student class:

```
class Student
{
public:
    Student();
    ~Student();
private:
    int age;
    char sex;
};
```

What I need to do with smart pointers is to handle files. For example: I have 5 files (s0.txt, s1.txt, s2.txt, s3.txt, s4.txt) and I want to list content of those files with use of smart pointers, subject to only 2 files can exist in memory at one time, aka before we read 3rd file 1st ifstream object should be deleted and that all should be done by Smart class smart pointers.

Any clues how i can handle this situation? I was able to accomplish task without smart pointers, but i have to use smart pointers with above conditions:

```
int main() {
    string fileName;
    int fileIndex = 0;

    int age;
    char sex;

    while (fileIndex != 5) {
        fileName = "Files/s" + to_string(fileIndex) + ".txt";
        ifstream fileRead(fileName);

        while (fileRead >> age >> sex) {

            cout << age << "\t" << sex<< endl;
        }

        fileIndex = fileIndex + 1;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have certain behavioural requirements, but I don't get how you come to the conclusion that smart pointers must somehow be involved.

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework, and that's fine.  But this is odd because you've got *two* problems here.  One is creating smart pointers, and another seems to be using them in a fairly sophisticated way.  Unless these are bizarro smart-pointers that delete themselves when more than 2 of them exist.  But then they wouldn't really be smart pointers...but something else.  Your linked list of `int` also isn't terribly useful.  At the moment, it's a pretty broad, slightly unclear question, and it wouldn't be easy to help you.

Comment: Or maybe you just need to **use** smart pointers?  In which case you should look at `shared_ptr` and `make_shared`

Comment: Basically when I run program, LinkedList should be created with 5 spots for students (i did it in constructor), then when we want to list content of 5 files we should use Smart class with ->() and *() functions and maybe others to fill those spots in LinedList. But there should not be more than 2 ifstream in memory at any time, any extra stuff should be stored back to files

Comment: Or at least this one: how i can make only 2 ifstream objects exist in memory at any time? If I run above main, there are 5 of them, i need only 2 at any time but so that all are printed